# Insert a text file into Oracle with Bulk Insert

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, bulkinsert

I have a place.file text file;

place.file

- New Hampshire
- New Jersey
- New Mexico
- Nevada
- New York
- Ohio
- Oklahoma
  ....

There are 4000 place names in this file. I will match my my_place table in oracle   and place.file . So I want to insert the place.file into the Oracle . Maybe I should use bulk insert, how can I do bulk insert ?

Comment: 4000 places is a very moderate amount of data. I don't see no need to use bulk insert or the like. Just use regular inserts.

Comment: @Codo Infact I want to learn using bulk insert. I gave a simple example maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No mention of an Oracle version.  (For the best possible answer, *always* include Oracle version, Oracle edition, OS, and OS version.)

However, you should investigate using an external table for this purpose.  Once you have that set up correctly, you can do:

```
insert into db_table select ... from external_table;
```

Optionally, you could use the `APPEND` hint on the `INSERT` statement, to use direct load.
Also,optionally, you could set the `NOLOGGING` attribute on the table you're loading the data into, for best performance.  But, consider the recovery implications before you enable `NOLOGGING`.

Hope that helps,

-Mark

Comment: Oracle version is 10.06 Os Windows7 .

Answer (score 4):

You can use SQL Loader from Oracle.

The syntax is:

> sqlldr *connection_string* control=*control_file.ctl*

The control file contains:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE names.file
INTO TABLE <table_name>
FIELDS TERMINATED BY <delimiter>
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY <enclosing character>
(<column_name>[, <column_name>, <column_name>])
```

Comment: I would also use SQL Loader. But again, his BULK insert is different I guess then both these answers. Though, in this case, it will be bulk insert which will be slower. ;)